# weakly conformal map

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Maybe an easy topology excercise. Say u is a weakly conformal map from a region of complex plane C to C. Then $u_z*{\bar u}_z=0$. How to derive that u is holomorphic or antiholomorphic, i.e. $u_z=0$ or $\bar u_z=0$ globally?

Comment: seems enough to show that u is analytic?

Comment: Found a proof. Show u is harmonic.